# ¿Cómo crear vídeo de fondo con css3?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

> La forma como estoy implementando el vídeo es la forma correcta para crear un vídeo de fondo.

Como reproduzco el vídeo de fondo automáticamente aplicando solo estilo css3 o es necesario añadir jQuery para reproducir el vídeo automáticamente.

> Cómo se oculta o se elimina los botones o las herramientas de reproducción de vídeo

```css
#background-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: -157.906px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 758.813px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-video ">
  <video poster="http://www.themesindustry.com/html/bizone/video/thumb.jpg">
    <source src="http://www.themesindustry.com/html/bizone/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de la etiqueta video agregar controls autoplay preload="auto"

Comment: perfecto el video se reproduce automaticamente pero se muestra los botones de reprodución.

Comment: quitale la palabra controls